# Meaning of "The one that looks out over the pond" in the following sentence?

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "The one that looks out over the pond" in the following sentence:

> As her dad unlocked the front door, Sally bolted through it. She ran
>   from room to room. "Which one's mine?" she asked excitedly.
>
> "The big corner room upstairs. The one that looks out over the pond,"
>   replied her mother.

Does it mean "The big corner room at which Sally can see the pond"?

What is the difference between "the one that Sally looks out over the pond" and "the one that looks out over the pond"?

Comment: It means "The big corner room **from** which Sally can see the pond."

Comment: If that is a relative adverb, is the subject ( Sally) omitted in the sentence (that looks out over the pond )?  What is the difference between "the one that (=from which) Sally looks out over the pond" and the one that (=from which)  looks out over the pond" ?

Comment: Forget about Sally. It's a metaphor—if something looks out over something, the former faces the latter from some upper point. _The house looks out over a peaceful rural landscape._

Comment: What research have you done? Which did you check for meanings of *look* or *look out over*?